# Concatenate cell array in only 1 dimension in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation, cell-array

I have a 2 dimensional cell of tables, `B`, in Matlab, i.e.:

```
A = table(normrnd(0,1,5,1),normrnd(0,1,5,1),normrnd(0,1,5,1));

B = {A,A,A,A;A,A,A,A}

B = 

[5x3 table]    [5x3 table]    [5x3 table]    [5x3 table]
[5x3 table]    [5x3 table]    [5x3 table]    [5x3 table]
```

I would like to concatenate the tables in the 1st dimension of the cell array (the 2 rows), but keep the cell structure in the other dimension. Thus, I would like to have the following:

```
{cat(1,B{:,1}),cat(1,B{:,2}),cat(1,B{:,3}),cat(1,B{:,3})}

ans = 

[10x3 table]    [10x3 table]    [10x3 table]    [10x3 table]
```

However, since my actual cell array has much more than 2 rows and 4 columns, this is not a suitable solution. I have tried using `cat` and `vertcat`, but I can't get them to not concatenate in the second dimension. Using ´cat´, I get:

```
cat(1,B{:})

ans = 

[40x3 table]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result = cellfun(@(a,b) cat(1,a,b),B(1,:),B(2,:),'UniformOutput',false);
```

The output:

```
result = 

    [10x3 table]    [10x3 table]    [10x3 table]    [10x3 table]
```

(We need to set `UniformOuput` to `false` because the contents of the output cells are not scalars.)

---

The contents of one of the cells in my case:

```
result{1}

ans = 

      Var1       Var2        Var3  
    ________    _______    ________

    -0.20497     0.6715      1.0347
    -0.12414    -1.2075     0.72689
      1.4897    0.71724    -0.30344
       1.409     1.6302     0.29387
      1.4172    0.48889    -0.78728
    -0.20497     0.6715      1.0347
    -0.12414    -1.2075     0.72689
      1.4897    0.71724    -0.30344
       1.409     1.6302     0.29387
      1.4172    0.48889    -0.78728
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but my real cell-array also have many rows, so I would need a solution where I don't need to add a cell-array for each row (B(1,:),B(2,:),...).

Comment: @Mace Off the top of my head I can't think of a solution without using `for` loops. I'll comment again if I come up with anything.

Comment: @Mace What type of data are in your tables? If it's all numerical we could do something with `cell2mat` and `mat2cell`, but I suspect there are things like variable-length strings too?

Comment: Yes, there will be both strings and numeric data